# My MacBook Pro won't connect to my Wi-Fi

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

My Wi-Fi router is provided by BT and works fine for my iPad and Mac mini. However, my MacBook Pro now won't connect to the router but will connect to the external BT hotspot.

When I try to log in it says invalid password. I've removed the router from the list via System Preferences → Network → Advanced but this has had no effect. I've tried adding `"` before and after the password—now I don't know what to do.

Comment: the external British Telecom does not require password? Does it work if you disable the password on the router ?

Comment: try using copy paste rather then typing the password.

Comment: Did this accessibility loss appeared just after a reboot of your BT router?

Comment: [This answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42046/wifi-connection-has-password-issue-with-my-macbook-pro/244109#244109) helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to scrap the existing Keychain.

Try this:

1. Go to Spotlight and type in "Keychain Access"
2. Search for your wireless network in the Keychain Access window
3. Delete any keys that appear here

Next, while you're at it, I'd recommend trashing your SysConfig folder. To do that:

1. Go to Finder
2. In the menu bar, click on Go > Go To Folder
3. Type in the following location:

   ```
   /Library/Preferences/
   ```
4. Then scroll to the bottom and drag the SystemConfiguration folder to the trash

Then restart your computer. When it is finished restarting, try reconnecting to your WiFi and enter the password. Let me know if it still does not work!

Comment: Have you called BT? It sounds like an issue with the two devices communicating. Additionally, if you are running OS X Yosemite, there were reports of MacBook Pro connectivity issues. Some have been cleared up with the latest update. May be worth calling in to AppleCare to see if they are checking the status of some of these issues (usually called an RTA).