# MacBook Wi-Fi can't connect on Connectify: invalid password

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi, password

I made a hotspot using a Wi-Fi external receiver connected on my laptop running Windows with a program named Connectify just today.

My PC gets the Internet connection via the Ethernet connection and share it with Connectify. The name of my Wi-Fi network is "connectify".

I have noticed that only my iPad and iPhone are able to connect to it.

My MacBook just says "invalid password" when I know for a fact that the password I configured is correct.

I've never been able to connect to my Wi-Fi network from my Macbook. I have already deleted the Wi-Fi location configuration and made a new one without sucess.

What might explain this MacBook or Wi-Fi failure?

Comment: What wifi receiver?

Comment: It's just a usb that can send internet to my iphone/ipad and windows laptop. Not macbook.

Comment: sorry, where is the USB connected to?

Comment: To a desktop pc connected via lan. It's sending the lan connection via wifi.

Comment: Does the hotspot have a maximum number of simultaneous client connections? Could the password error be a red herring because of bad error-handling from the receiver/misinterpretation from OS X?  Try to find out if there is a max connection limit to your hotspot. Also, try rebooting your Mac.  I have received invalid password errors from completely valid DD-WRT access points, and it was resolved by either rebooting my Mac or rebooting the router. Just reboot everything and see if it resolves itself.

Comment: [This answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42046/wifi-connection-has-password-issue-with-my-macbook-pro/244109#244109) helped me.

Comment: Did you finaly understand and fix your network problem?

Answer (score 1):

Lets try to reset your Macs settings.

```
            Go to System Preferences > Network.
            Click the Wi-Fi connection.
            Click the Advanced... button on the bottom right.
            Click the Wi-Fi tab.
            Under Preferred Networks, select your wireless network.
            Click the - (delete) button.
            Turn off your Wi-Fi connection.
            Turn it back on.
            Select and login to your wireless network. This will re-save your connection under Preferred Networks.
            Close your laptop and reopen it to test whether it worked.
```

Next would be to try connecting manually using your Terminal (located in the Utility Folder.

Copy following in to your Termial:

To find the Network

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport scan
```

To Connect

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 WIFI_SSID_I_WANT_TO_JOIN WIFI_PASSWORD
```

Replace the SSID and Password with your data.

Comment: There are no preferred networks also terminal says to me "failed to join network" Error: -3924 invalid PMKlocalhost:~ home$"

Comment: Does the first command list the network ?

Comment: Yes it does show the connectify.

Comment: Sorry, connectify is the SSID (network name) ?

Comment: Yes connectify is the SSID.

Answer (score 1):

Before try association, can you please try if your device is able to scan your desired SSID properly (RSSI value not less than -60 dBm - -70 dBm).

1. Click on your apple logo.
2. Select "About this Mac"
3. Select System Report
4. Goto "Network" section and select "Wi-Fi"

in this you will get all the network which your mac is able to scan.
Look for your desired SSID and look for "Signal/Noise" field. Signal Strength value i.e. RSSI should not be low than -60 dBm for healthy connection.

Sometimes it is seen; when cable connected with Wi-Fi card is loosen it scans the Wi-Fi network at very low rssi, which in result affect the association.